# Unable to keep <span> text contained

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar widget that I am trying to style using CSS. Here's the HTML (I have omitted all but two `<li>` nodes for the sake of brevity):

```css
.tagcloud, .trending-box {
     padding: 1em;
     background-color: #f3f3f3;
     border: none;
     border-top: none;
    
    }
    .tagcloud > a, .trending-box > ul > li > span.tptn_after_thumb > a { color: #7b6100; }
    .trending-box > ul > li { list-style-type: none; margin-bottom: 1em; }
    .trending-box > ul > li:last-child { margin-bottom: 0px; }
    .trending-box > ul { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
    .trending-box > ul > li > span.tptn_after_thumb { margin-left: 1em; }
    .trending-box > ul > li.trend-item > span.imagespan > a > img {
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     border-radius: 50% !important;
    }
```

```html
<div class="trending-box">
     <ul id="trending-list">
      <li class="trend-item">
       <span class="imagespan">
        <a href="" class="tptn_link">
         <img src="http://i.imgur.com/mj70dV9.jpg" width="150" height="150" class="tptn_thumb tptn_featured">
       </a>
       </span>
       <span class="tptn_after_thumb">
        <a href="" class="tptn_link">
         <span class="tptn_title">
          Lorem Ipsum is a Dummy Text
         </span>
        </a>
       </span>
      </li>
      <li class="trend-item">
       <span class="imagespan">
        <a href="" class="tptn_link">
         <img src="http://i.imgur.com/mj70dV9.jpg" width="150" height="150" class="tptn_thumb tptn_featured">
        </a>
       </span>
       <span class="tptn_after_thumb">
        <a href="" class="tptn_link">
         <span class="tptn_title">
          Lorem is Lorem and Ipsum is Ipsum but Lorem is Lorem and Ipsum is Ipsum
         </span>
        </a>
       </span>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Now, as you can see in the image below, my problem is with the `span.tptn_after_thumb` elements. Somehow, the contents are spilling over outside the `span`, resulting in an ugly gap between two `<li>` items (see the second last list item in the screenshot below). I tried adding `display: block` and `display: inline-block` to either and both the spans (`.imagespan` which contains the image and `.tptn_after_thumb` which contains the text) but neither worked. What else would you advice me to do? I need the text to wrap inside its `span` so as to avoid any irregular vertical gap between the images.

[image]

**UPDATE**: Here's a screenshot showing the results of implementing LOTUSMS' solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Bootstrap (or any other responsive framework for that matter), if you divide the `spans` within the `li` container to total 100% width, you will get that effect, as long as the are `display: inline-block`. Meaning you as absorbing all of the width and height of the `span` as your container. This overwrites the `span's` native inline-only display.

In this example and my demo I only added this rule to the span in question, but ideally you want to assign the remaining 25% to the sibling span

Use this **EDITED**

```
.trending-box > ul > li > span{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
.trending-box > ul > li > span.tptn_after_thumb {
    margin-left: 1em;
    width:75%;
}
```

See the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/OMEpPq)

Comment: Kinda works but two problems: 1) I am a tad reluctant to hardcode dimensions and would prefer a solution that doesn't require specifying width or height, and 2) It forces the offending text to slightly shift above the baseline making it look misaligned. I will post a screenshot right away...

Comment: Using widths is not bad, using fixed widths is bad. percentages are flexible widths which is the correct way to do it. As I said, "inspired by bootstrap and all other responsive frameworks" Now, unto your alignment issue, nothing that a vertical-align and/or padding cant fix

Comment: You didn't read my explanation where I said my code in this answer only shows one span, but you have to do the same to both span, and distribute the widths to sum up to 100%. So that is adjusts to any browser's size. So I edited the answer to show what you have to do to both spans. That eliminates the alignment issue. :)

Comment: Perfect! This worked, although adding 25% to the sibling span squished the images vertically making them horribly oval instead of round. So I went with just assigning 75% to the text span and leaving the sibling be. valign did fix the alignment issue as you said. I hope not assigning 25% to the sibling is not going to be a problem responsiveness-wise.

Comment: Oh yeah, actually I forgot your images are not wrapped inside the span. My bad. I normally don't architect my HTML like this to avoid this very issue. By wrapping the image inside another span, you can still size the span accordingly but not the actual image. But its fine. This works too.